# POST variables with html5 Formdata File Upload in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm uploading images with HTML5 formdata and PHP

I have appended the files to the formdata, --> xhr.send(formdata),
now I can get to the files using $_FILES in PHP.

How can I send additional variables to the PHP file? There's no $_POST['var']?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation from MDN is pretty clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
formdata.append('var', 'value')
```

Comment: Thanks! I lost track of the easy solution!